# Can we configure VM diagnostics logs to the table storage using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm using azure ARM templates to deploy VMs. Is there any way to configure diagnostics logs to the table storage using ARM templates.

Comment: you are referring to this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json#L172 ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json#add-the-azure-diagnostics-extension-to-the-vm-resource-definition) is the link which helps to enable VM diagnostic logs. Please note when you enable the diagnostic logs for the virtual machines , the logs are automatically stored in storage account tables.

Below are few tables and information stored in them

WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable - Diagnostic monitor and configuration changes WADPerformanceCountersTable - Performance counters
WADWindowsEventLogsTable  - Windows Event Logs